# Fixing tab spacing on chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to autofix the indentation on the new chrome dev tools when the source files are attached to the local files?

I just started using it instead of komodo as my default editor. Something like control + E, control + D in visual studio

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Update: the setting now falls under

> Chrome Dev Tools -> Settings -> Preferences -> Sources -> Default indendtation

Comment: Following changing indention I had to run the prettyfier {} to take effect the change (Chrome 79)

Answer (score 5):

It is now... yay!

Chrome Dev Tools -> Settings -> General -> Default Indentation

[image]

May need a restart.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible; feel free to request this feature on [chromium bugtracker](http://bugs.chromium.org).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know if I could add the feature?